# LinkedIn API to fetch an independent user latest activity

Tags: rest, visualization, linkedin-api

My use case is simple. Assuming the respective LinkedIn user X is authenticated, check if X made an organic post within the current day. If so `True`, if not `False`. The visualization of this functionality would be IDENTICAL to Github Contributions, but for LinkedIn posts.

I looked over the [Community Management API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http), but this seems to be more oriented towards organizations and their members.

*I seek a LinkedIn API call that will work on ANY authenticated LinkedIn user.*

Comment: you can take reference fromhere : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=curl#find-shares-by-owner